# Magento 2 migration: apply configurable product's price to it's simple products

Tags: configurable-product, price, migration

We did M1 -> M2 migration and now we need to set the price of each simple product associated with a configurable product to have the price of the configurable product. Is there a way to do this?

It seems that migration script indeed imported the price for configurable products even if it is shown blank in the product data page in admin. The product list page in admin shows the price for each configurable product.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you want to set the price of some products or all products. However, if you find a reliable automated migration tool to migrate your data from Magento 1 to Magento 2, you will find no issue when importing the price of products to Magento 2.